# Installing Floobits with VIM

Tags: vim, plugins

I'm trying to install the VIM Floobits plugin, but I'm having a lot of difficulty.
First off, I installed VIM from the VIM website and then I tried using [Vundle](https://github.com/gmarik/Vundle.vim) to install the [VIM Floobits Plugin](https://github.com/Floobits/floobits-vim).
The issue was that when I tried running the`:PluginInstall`command, I got the message "Sorry, the Floobits Vim plugin requires a Vim compiled with +python"
I'm not really sure what that means. So I looked that up and tried to use MinGW to compile vim with +python. That did not work. Next I tried building VIM from the sources, but the `configure` command does not work on Windows.
Does anyone know how to properly install Floobits for console VIM?
Oh, and here's the lines from my `~/.vimrc` that pertain to Vundle:

```
" VUNDLE
set nocompatible                    " required
filetype off                        " required
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim   " set the runtime path to include Vundle and initialize
call vundle#begin()                 " begin vundle
Plugin 'gmarik/Vundle.vim'          " let Vundle manage Vundle, required
Plugin 'Floobits/floobits-vim'      " add the floobits plugin
call vundle#end()                   " required; all plugins must be added before this line
```

Comment: On a side note: it's a good idea to avoid comments at end of line.  The syntax for command mode combined with the fact that `"` is also a string delimiter can lead to unexpected effects.

Comment: You're saying each comment should get it's own line then?

Comment: That's the safest choice, yes.

Answer (score 0):

You can find proper Vim builds for Windows here:

- https://tuxproject.de/projects/vim/
- http://solar-blogg.blogspot.ca/p/vim-build.html

Comment: Hmm. Thank you for this. However, now when I use the `:version` command, I see that vim has `+python`, but I'm still getting the message that it needs to be compiled with `+python`. Any idea why that could be?